# Counting words in a sqlite FTS4

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite3 full text search table defined like this:

```
 CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE entries USING fts4 ( entry TEXT )
```

Each entry row has a line of text. How can I write a query to count the total amount of words in the table? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a built-in function to do that, but you could re-use the answer to
" [Query to count words SQLite 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293790/query-to-count-words-sql-lite-3) " to get the total count of words:

```
select sum(length(trim(entry)) 
        - length(replace(trim(entry), ' ', '')) + 1) from entries;
```

(Modified the original answer by adding the `trim`.)

If you have `sqlite3` version 3.7.6 or later, you can do something cleaner with an [`fts4aux` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#fts4aux).

```
create virtual table terms using fts4aux(entries);
select count(distinct term) from terms;
```