# SQL Replace() table join only replaces trailing text

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I'm using .Net 2013, which I believe comes packaged with a version of SQL Server.

**EDIT:**
I understand the example is rather odd, it's just an illustration of an issue I encountered while working out a resolution to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028757/calculating-total-value-of-numeric-values-assigned-to-string-tokens-in-sql-colum)

**EDIT 2:**
My expected results are apparently NOT what people are expecting, so adding to bottom.  Sorry for the confusion.

**Hopefully Final Edit**
I changed the tables from variations of Hello World to Bacon & Eggs.
After reading this a few times to make sure I'm very clear on what the issue is, I was going cross-eyed.  Changed the source data to be more legible.  Issue remains. I checked.

I have two tables. 
One containing a string. 
One containing a string to be replaced, as well as its replacement.

```
*String Table*
Bacon
Eggs
Bacon & Eggs                                        
Eggs & Bacon                                        

*Replacement Table*
Bacon       Pork                                       
Eggs        Poultry
```

I then have a View that does a cross join to perform the replace, but it is not working properly.  This has me baffled, because it seems to only replace the string at the END.  See the query results below.

```
SELECT  InitialString, ReplacementTarget, ReplacementValue, 
        REPLACE(InitialString, ReplacementTarget, ReplacementValue) 
            AS ReplacedString
FROM    StringTable CROSS JOIN ReplacementTable
```

Note that only the last half of the text is replaced.
It's not like the first replacement is made, then it stops.  That at least would make sense.
This is literally like the replacement isn't validating for some reason.

**RESULTS OF QUERY**  (issues marked with asterisk)

```
InitialString   ReplaceTarget  ReplaceValue     ReplacedString
Bacon           Bacon          Pork             Pork                    
Eggs            Bacon          Pork             Eggs                    
Bacon & Eggs    Bacon          Pork             Bacon* & Eggs            
Eggs & Bacon    Bacon          Pork             Eggs & Pork             
Bacon           Eggs           Poultry          Bacon                   
Eggs            Eggs           Poultry          Poultry                 
Bacon & Eggs    Eggs           Poultry          Bacon & Poultry         
Eggs & Bacon    Eggs           Poultry          Eggs* & Bacon
```

.
**EXPECTED RESULTS (YES, I WANT 8 ROWS BACK.  SEE LINK ABOVE)**
(changes denoted with asterisk)

```
InitialString   ReplaceTarget  ReplaceValue     ReplacedString
Bacon           Bacon          Pork             Pork                    
Eggs            Bacon          Pork             Eggs                    
Bacon & Eggs    Bacon          Pork             Pork* & Eggs            
Eggs & Bacon    Bacon          Pork             Eggs & Pork             
Bacon           Eggs           Poultry          Bacon                   
Eggs            Eggs           Poultry          Poultry                 
Bacon & Eggs    Eggs           Poultry          Bacon & Poultry         
Eggs & Bacon    Eggs           Poultry          Poultry* & Bacon
```

.

Any help or insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Comment: Oddly enough, your exact query works fine when I run it in SSMS SQL Server 2008.  Could you have an invisible character in your data, like a newline?

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  I actually created the mockup data above and tested my query to rule out everything but the most basic of variables.  The data above is literally a copy/paste.

Comment: Actually, I'm expecting 8 rows.  I'm thinking this was a bad example, I'll update the initial question with a clarification.

Comment: I'm speculating that if the data were loaded from a file, then it is possible it is capturing an end-line character into the table data, causing it to only replace the part that matches the newline, ergo, the second word.

Comment: If you change your query to something like `SELECT DATALENGTH(InitialString), DATALENGTH(ReplacementTarget), DATALENGTH(ReplacementValue)...` do you see the lengths you expect (5 for Bacon, etc.)? Is it possible that you're using a different system collation than we are?

Comment: Maybe you're using *SQL Server 2014 Community Technology Preview 1*. Microsoft has not debugged it sufficiently and has not certified it for running business software; that version is only for folks who want to get a preview of upcoming features. Your code works fine for me on SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition. Why not use the latest SQL Server Express? It's free.

Comment: This works as expected [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab0f1/1).

Comment: @John - I tried installing SQL Express 2005, but it isn't compatible with Windows 8.  I tried 2008, but can't get it to work either.  Had to un-install .NET 2013, installed .NET 2012.  SQL failed to install correctly.  I've pretty much given up for now.  I'll try again next weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is pretty stupid/funny.  A friend asked if I was using TRIM()

```
SELECT InitialString, ReplacementTarget, ReplacementValue, 
       REPLACE(InitialString, RTRIM(ReplacementTarget), RTRIM(ReplacementValue)) 
            AS ReplacedString
FROM   StringTable CROSS JOIN ReplacementTable
```

Makes perfect sense, in hindsight.  Only the TRAILING target had the requisite trailing spaces!