# MYSQL count how many times SOME value is exist as value in a field of table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MYSQL Check If **some** value is exist as value in a field of table

I have table A with field :
id      name     value
1       item1      822
2       item2      658
3       item3      321

I'm trying to figure out this :
I want to count how many times values is exist in a field
example :
If I'm searching 2 and 8, then

The Result is :
The count is 3 for row id 1 ( because it's has two 2 and one 8 )
And the count is 1 for row id 2 ( because it's has one 8 number )
And the count is 1 for row id 3 ( because it's has one 2 number )

Comment: Column value's data type? (Horrible column name...)

Comment: the data type is varchar for value, dont care about the column name, its just example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count instances of character in SQL Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860457/how-to-count-instances-of-character-in-sql-column)

Comment: no it's different, I'm asking how to count 2 value, the link you give just count 1 value in a field

Comment: omg, sorry I miss that, my wrong, I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `replace()` and `length()` (or `char_length()`):

```
select (length(value) - length(replace(replace(value, '2', ''), '8', ''))) as num_occurrences
from t;
```

Comment: wait.. I think your answer is better @Gordon Linoff, because with your code, if value is 2828, it will count 4, nice

Comment: @Ridho, you said you wanted count 2 for row id 1 (822), because it has an 8 and a 2. Have you changed your mind?

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, case when value like '%2%' then 1 else 0 end +
               case when value like '%8%' then 1 else 0 end
from tablename
```