# Count the number of not null columns using a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with my query...I am trying to get a count of names in each house, all the col#'s are names.

Query:

```
SELECT House#,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    COUNT(CASE WHEN col#3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count
  FROM myDB
 WHERE House# in (house#1,house#2,house#3)
 GROUP BY House#
```

Desired results:

house 1 - the count is 3 /
house 2 - the count is 2 /
house 3 - the count is 1

...with my current query the results for count would be just 3's

Comment: are they always separated by a comma?

Comment: If you are able to change the database schema, I suggest you do that instead. Comma-separated values in a column is not a great idea. You ideally would have a `HouseName` table that just has one house/name combination per row. Then your query becomes a simple count/group.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of firstname,lastname or any other commas?

Comment: sorry I was a bit (very) vague... the commas just separate the names. If I was to write it in a question/answer  paragraph, it would be... peter, paul and mary live in house 1. sarah and sally live in house 2. joe lives in house 3. how may people live in house 1 and house 2 and house 3....answer, respectfully is 3,2,1

Comment: I am pretty sure I need to use a counter (loop?) but can't find anything on stackoverflow or online that address this...

Comment: This is a very **very** different problem than the one posted in the question

Comment: yes, I realize that....sorry about that! just when I thought I was doing well in advancing with sql, I then find myself still at the 2nd grade level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count instances of character in SQL Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860457/how-to-count-instances-of-character-in-sql-column)

Comment: I am not sure about the protocol because the question I asked was not very clear...please advise.In case I can leave it be, here is the query I would use and the results are the same as I indicated above;SELECT
houseNo,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN name1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        COUNT(CASE WHEN name4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
FROM mydatabase
GROUP BY houseNo

Comment: Just FYI, `COUNT(CASE WHEN name1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` should not return anything different than `COUNT(name1)` as `NULL` values are not counted by the `COUNT()` aggregate function.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, it seems that counting names is the same as counting the commas (`,`) plus one:

```
SELECT House_Name, 
       LEN(Names) - LEN(REPLACE(Names,',','')) + 1 as Names
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: @scsimon yeah, sorry, I normally wait for clarification, but for some reason I thought in this was case was pretty clear...my bad

Answer (score 2):

Another option since [Lamak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519216/lamak) stole my thunder, would be to split it and normalize your data, and then aggregate. This uses a [common split function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) but you could use anything, including [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) for SQL Server 2016+ or your own...

```
declare @table table (house varchar(16), names varchar(256))
insert into @table 
values
('house 1','peter, paul, mary'),
('house 2','sarah, sally'),
('house 3','joe')

select
    t.house
    ,NumberOfNames = count(s.Item)
from
    @table t
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(names,',') s
group by
    t.house
```

Comment: Good one. Though reading the last comment by the op, we are all very wrong

Comment: HAHA, we were way of judging by that comment @Lamak

Comment: yeah, I don't think that something like that can be done with 100% precision in sql

Answer (score 1):

Notice how the answers you are getting are quite complex for what they're doing? That's because relational databases are not designed to store data that way.

On the other hand, if you change your data structure to something like this:

```
house   name
1       peter
1       paul
1       mary
2       sarah
2       sally
3       joe
```

The query now is:

```
select house, count(name)
from housenames
group by house
```

So my recommendation is to do that: use a design that's more suitable for SQL Server to work with, and your queries become simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One dirty trick is to replace commas with empty strings and compare the lengths:

```
SELECT house + 
       ' has ' + 
       CAST((LEN(names) - LEN(REPLACE(names, ',', '')) + 1) AS VARCHAR) +
       ' names'
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse using xml and find count as below:

```
Select *, a.xm.value('count(/x)','int') from (
    Select *, xm = CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(names,', ','$$$SSText$$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$$SSText$$$','</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML)   from #housedata
) a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select House, 'has '+cast((LEN(Names)-LEN(REPLACE(Names, ',', ''))+1) as varchar)+' names' 
from TempTable
```