# Get a string from a sentence with the occurence of another String

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a column Col1 which has values as below:

```
SELECT 'XXX-T09-CFO Signature' AS  Col1
UNION 
SELECT 'YYY-T140 - Update Funding Authorization Status to Completed'
UNION 
SELECT'ZZZ-T13-PAB Chair Signature'
```

My output col2 should have string before the word "Signature" from col1.If the word Signature is not found it should be set to NULL

```
SELECT 'XXX-T09-CFO Signature' AS  Col1,'CFO' as Col2
UNION 
SELECT 'YYY-T140 - Update Funding Authorization Status to Completed' ,Null
UNION 
SELECT'ZZZ-T13-PAB Chair Signature','PAB Chair'
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly your question is? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish or where you are running into problems.

Comment: my output should have values mentioned in Col2. If the string is "'XXX-T09-CFO Signature' " ,my O/P should be first string before the keyword Signature I,e "CFO"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use STRING_SPLIT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions

I'll demonstrate using it once (without testing), but you could use it twice to get what you want, once splitting on the dash and once on the space

```
SELECT Word
FROM
    (
     SELECT 'XXX-T09-CFO Signature' AS Word,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Var, '-')
    ) T
WHERE RN == 3;
```

Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54026051/11817085

Comment: No, that's wrong. First, string_split was introduced in 2016, the OP is working with 2008r2. Second, that's not reliable. `order by (select null)` will produce an arbitrary row number, and string_split returns a table with the parts of the string, but no order column. For more information, read [The “Natural order” misconception](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that 2008 and 2008r2 [are no longer supported](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/). Their extended support period ended last year - in July 9th 2019.
You should seriously consider upgrading your SQL Server version (note that 2012 is also going out of extended support in a couple of years - July 12, 2022.)

That being said, Here's a solution that will work on 2008r2 as well as on all currently supported versions - using a combination of `case`, `charindex`, `right`, and `reverse`:

```
WITH SourceTable AS
(
    SELECT 'XXX-T09-CFO Signature' AS  Col1
    UNION 
    SELECT 'YYY-T140 - Update Funding Authorization Status to Completed'
    UNION 
    SELECT'ZZZ-T13-PAB Chair Signature'
), CTE AS
(
    SELECT Col1,
           SUBSTRING(Col1, 0, CHARINDEX('Signature', Col1)) As BeforeSignature
    FROM SourceTable
)

SELECT  Col1, 
        CASE WHEN BeforeSignature = '' THEN 
            NULL 
        ELSE 
            RIGHT(BeforeSignature, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(BeforeSignature))-1)
        END As Col2
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Col1                                                            Col2
XXX-T09-CFO Signature                                           CFO 
YYY-T140 - Update Funding Authorization Status to Completed     NULL
ZZZ-T13-PAB Chair Signature                                     PAB Chair
```