# how to find the biggest procedure in the database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i am using SQL Server 2008 R2,
i have lots of procedures in the database. 
amongest those i want to find the biggest procedure in terms of rows ?
is it possible to find the procedure having the count as their number of rows in it.
please can somebody help me to get this.

Thanks! in adavanced.

Comment: The number of rows emitted by a procedure might vary dependant upon current data and parameters passed in. You could set up a trace capturing the procedure calls and the `rows` column. Not sure how useful that would be though. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this [substring count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch) solution to count the line breaks (nchar(10)):

```
select o.type, o.name, 
    len(m.definition) - len(replace(m.definition, nchar(10), '')) as rows,
    m.* 
from sys.sql_modules m
inner join sys.objects o on m.object_id = o.object_id
--order by type, name
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: Oh I see what they are asking now!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for something like:

```
select 
    routine_name, 
    DATALENGTH(ROUTINE_DEFINITION) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of character count instead of rowcount you can try this one:

```
select p.name, len(m.definition)
from sys.procedures p
join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id=p.object_id
order by len(m.definition) desc
```