# Query to return the number of times a specific value occurs within a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Alright so I have two tables. Table1 has an reference number column (A), and a second column that has a string of randomness (B). Table2 has only one column with a list of values that may or may not be in the string on Table1.

**dbo.Tbl_1**

```
+--+---------------------------------------+
|A |B                                      |
+--+---------------------------------------+
|24|BLUE; KITTEN; WHITE; PINK; SLOPE; GREEN|
+--+---------------------------------------+
|51|GREEN; CLOUDY; WHITE; CHIPS            |
+--+---------------------------------------+
|78|PATRIOTS; PINK; PINK; WHITE            |
+--+---------------------------------------+
|22|WHITE; RED; TREES; AMY; GREEN          |
+--+---------------------------------------+
```

**dbo.Tbl_2**

```
+-----+
|C    |
+-----+
|BLUE |
+-----+
|WHITE|
+-----+
|PINK |
+-----+
|BROWN|
+-----+
```

What sql query would determine how many times a value from Table2 is found in the string on Table1?  Basically I want to return the below result set:

```
+-----+----+
|BLUE |1   |
+-----+----+
|WHITE|4   |
+-----+----+
|PINK |3   |
+-----+----+
|BROWN|NULL|
+-----+----+
```

FYI: In reality, Table2 has about 200 unique records. Table1 has about 1.6M records with unique reference numbers. Neither tables are static.

Comment: is there always going to be only one instance of a color in tbl 1 col B?  i.e. in tbl 1 id 24 could never have BLUE twice on the same record

Comment: Rather than asking "How I do X", you should try out some queries on your own, and tell us what you've tried and what specifically isn't working.

Comment: @Bethany_93 your table `dbo.Tbl_1` not in normal form. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a bit and came up with this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65926/15/0)

The relevant SELECT query looks like this (requires two table scans though, I'm sure it can be made more efficient):

```
select C, sum(dbo.CountOccurancesOfString(B, C)) as number
from Tbl_1 join Tbl_2 on 1=1
group by C
order by number desc
```

**EDIT** This is the function I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountOccurancesOfString
(
 @searchString nvarchar(max),
 @searchTerm nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
 return (LEN(@searchString)-LEN(REPLACE(@searchString,@searchTerm,'')))/LEN(@searchTerm)
END
```

Comment: This solution only works as long as all values in Tbl_2 are **not** substrings of other items in the table. For example, **GREEN vs. LIGHTGREEN** (`GREEN` would be double counted in this case).

Comment: wdosanjos - you are of course right. I suppose the split approach by M.Ali is better as the countoccurrences function would have to be drastically changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Split Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END
```

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @Table_1 TABLE ([A] INT,[B] VARCHAR(1000)) 
INSERT INTO @Table_1 VALUES
(24,'BLUE; KITTEN; WHITE; PINK; SLOPE; GREEN'),
(51,'GREEN; CLOUDY; WHITE; CHIPS'), 
(78,'PATRIOTS; PINK; PINK; WHITE'), 
(22,'WHITE; RED; TREES; AMY; GREEN')

DECLARE @Table_2 TABLE (ColumnName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Table_2 VALUES 
('BLUE'),('WHITE'),('PINK'),('BROWN')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T2.ColumnName, TotalNums
 FROM 
(SELECT Data, COUNT(DATA) TotalNums 
FROM  @Table_1 t  CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](t.B, ';'))C
GROUP BY Data) T1
RIGHT JOIN @Table_2 T2 
ON T1.Data = T2.ColumnName
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ColumnName ║ TotalNums ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╣
║ BLUE       ║ 1         ║
║ WHITE      ║ 4         ║
║ PINK       ║ 3         ║
║ BROWN      ║ NULL      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╝
```