# How to split string on two characters or delimiters in sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, string, split

i'm trying to split this string "1,1_5,2_3,4" first on '_' and then split the sub string on ',' so it will be like "1,1_5,2_3,4" split-ed on '_' first so it will give this sub string "1,1" then this sub string split-ed on ',' and then insert the split-ed sub string "1 1" into temp table like this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST] ([X],[Y])
                  VALUES (@X,@Y)
```

i did this with only split on one delimiter ',' like this 
first i create a table Split function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @RowData nvarchar(2000),
        @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @cnt = 1

    While(charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData) > 0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select
            Data = ltrim(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData,1,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1))) 

            set @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
            set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End
        insert into @RtnValue(data)
        select Data =  ltrim(RTRIM(@RowData))
    RETURN

END
```

then i create this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspTest]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @StringOFXIDs nvarchar(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SOMETABLE TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) UNIQUE, XID INT);
    DECLARE @XCOUNT INT;
    DECLARE @XCURRENT INT;
    DECLARE @XCOUNTER INT = 1;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO @SOMETABLE([XID])
    SELECT [Data] FROM [dbo].[Split](@StringOFXIDs,',');

    SELECT @XCOUNT = COUNT(1) FROM @SOMETABLE;
    WHILE (@XCOUNTER <= @XCOUNT)
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @XCOUNTER = [XID]
        FROM @SOMETABLE
        WHERE [ID]  = @XCOUNTER

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[TEST] ([X])
                          VALUES (@XCOUNTER)
        SELECT @XCOUNTER +=1;
    END
END

--EXEC [dbo].[uspTest] '1,2,3,4'
```

and then execute this stored procedure and every thing work but i can't figure out how to split the string on two characters or delimiters and then inserted to temp table thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your string splitter is the slowest of all the various ways of splitting string in t-sql. Check out this article for a number of ways of splitting strings that will be better for performance.

Comment: What would you expect for output based on your example of '1,1_5,2_3,4'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246446/split-string-in-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use XML functionality to split into rows, then split into columns:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = '1,1_5,2_3,4'
;WITH cte AS (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Txt
                     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RN    
              FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@string, '_', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS DATA
                    ) AS A 
                     CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
              )
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT CONVERT(XML,'<String><Section>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(Txt ,'|',','),',', '</Section><Section>') + '</Section></String>') AS Txt
                      ,RN
               FROM cte
               )   
 SELECT Txt.value('/String[1]/Section[1]','varchar(100)') AS Col1
       ,Txt.value('/String[1]/Section[2]','varchar(100)') AS Col2
FROM  cte2
ORDER BY RN
```

Outputs:

```
Col1       Col2
---------------
1             1
5             2
3             4
```