# get array length after splitting string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to be able to split a string in SQL Server . I have a sample string

```
1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012
```

Here need length after splitting this string.

```
Expected output: 8
```

Comment: Can you say the expected output

Comment: @RajaYuvi, expected output length:8

Comment: if this is the input '1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1011,1011,1011,1011'.what wil be the expected output??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you count the number of occurrences of a certain substring in a SQL varchar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only need the number of items in a delimited string, you don't need to split it at all - here is how to do it:
You subtract the length of the string after removing all the delimiters from the length of the original string. This gives you the number of delimiters in the string. Then all you have to do is add one, since you have one more item then delimiters:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(50) = '1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012'

SELECT LEN(@String) - LEN(REPLACE(@String, ',', '')) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, great but no need adding 1

Comment: You have 8 items and 7 delimiters. the subtracting of lengths gives you the  number of delimiters.

Comment: @Shohel : you have to add 1

Comment: @Ullas, '1012' contains eight times into my string

Comment: @Shohel : Yes 8 items. `LEN(@String) - LEN(REPLACE(@String, ',', ''))` will retrieve the total number of commas ie. 7. So we have to add 1 with that.

Answer (score 5):

I think, to just find the total items in the string you may no need to split the string. Just need to find the number of occurrence of `,`.

**Query**

```
declare @string varchar(100)
set @string = '1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012,1012'

select len(@string ) - len(replace(@string ,',', '')) + 1;
```

### <kbd>[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/500265/number-of-occurences)</kbd>

Comment: sometimes you win the race, sometimes you don't :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled : Yep.. :)

Comment: some string comes with , at the prefix and postfix or even part of content, so counting commas are a no.