# How to get count of available guid from a comma separated string of guid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
Declare @i int;
declare @stringOfGuids nvarchar(max)='''70173C2D-0B8E-4043-BD14-665D5DCCF112'',''B0B7445C-DF50-4D49-BD4E-B74958FB0618''
,''70173C2D-0B8E-4043-BD14-665D5DCCF112''';
```

I have this string and I need to count the number of available guid which is three.

How can I get it in a Integer variable?

Something like this ?

```
select @i = count(@stringOfGuids)
```

but it returns 1, I need three as available guids are 3.

Comment: one way is to count the number of " characters in the string, then divide it by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @i int;

declare @stringOfGuids nvarchar(max)='''70173C2D-0B8E-4043-BD14-665D5DCCF112'',''B0B7445C-DF50-4D49-BD4E-B74958FB0618'' ,''70173C2D-0B8E-4043-BD14-665D5DCCF112''';

declare @cnt int = 0;
declare @pos int = 1;

while charindex('''', @stringOfGuids, @pos) > 0
    SELECT @pos =  charindex('''', @stringOfGuids, @pos) + 1, @CNT = @CNT + 1;



SELECT @CNT / 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Count the number of commas and add 1.

```
SELECT Len(@stringOfGuids ) - Len(Replace( @stringOfGuids , ',', '')) + 1
```

The counting is [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch).

Comment: that's ingenious!  He might want to count the quotes that way though, cos he's got a colon at the end I think - oh yeah sorry, add 1

Comment: yes, excellent Marko, it worked for me ,, thnx alot..good decent solution..