# ORDER BY C# Enum Flags most matches

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Given the following Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum CheeseCharacteristic 
{
    Yellow = 1,
    Stinks = 2,
    Squeaks = 4,
    Holey = 8,
    Mouldy = 16,
    UseOnToast = 32
}
```

And an entity `Cheese` having the property `Characteristic`, is it possible to order Cheeses based on how many flags are matched against the `Characteristic`?  For example, say a `Stilton` has the `Characteristic` value `Yellow`, `Stinks`, `Mouldy` and a `MildCheddar` has the `Characteristic` value `Yellow`, `UseOnToast`, is it possible to order by the number of matches for a given query?

So if I want to compare a collection of `Cheese` entities against `Yellow`, `Mouldy` then both `Stilton` and `MildCheddar` are returned, but the `Stilton` is top of the list as it has 2 matches.

To take this further, if I store the enum value in SQL Server, can I perform this sort in the DB using EF Core?

Comment: Maybe you could create a function that counts set bits in an integer value and use that count to order by as solution to your first question. As for if and how this could be done in the DB using EF Core I have no idea...

Answer (score 0):

I like this version because it maintains type safety while working with any bitmask enum.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;



namespace SO_58416947_count_bitmask_flags {
    static class Program {

        [Flags]
        public enum CheeseCharacteristics {
            Yellow = 1,
            Stinky = 2,
            Squeaky = 4,
            Holey = 8,
            Mouldy = 16,
            Spreadable = 32,
            UseOnToast = Yellow | Spreadable
        }


        static void Main(string[] args) {
            List<CheeseCharacteristics> _testCases = new List<CheeseCharacteristics>() {
                {CheeseCharacteristics.UseOnToast | CheeseCharacteristics.Stinky},
                {CheeseCharacteristics.Yellow | CheeseCharacteristics.Holey},   //  Swiss
                {CheeseCharacteristics.Squeaky},
                {CheeseCharacteristics.Mouldy | CheeseCharacteristics.Spreadable}
            };

            List<CheeseCharacteristics> cases = _testCases.OrderByFlagCount();

            foreach(CheeseCharacteristics c in cases) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{c}");
            }
        }   //  Main()



        private static List<T> GetIndividualFlagValues<T>() where T:Enum {
            Type enumType = typeof(T);

            if (!enumType.IsEnum) { throw new ArgumentException("Must pass an enum type."); }

            List<T> result = new List<T>();

            foreach(T item in Enum.GetValues(enumType)) {
                result.Add(item);
            }

            return result;
        }   //  GetIndividualFlagValues()



        //extension method
        public static List<T> OrderByFlagCount<T>(this List<T> list) where T:Enum {
            List<T> flags = GetIndividualFlagValues<T>();
            List<T> results = list
                .OrderBy(t => flags.Where(f => true == t.HasFlag(f)).Count())
                .ToList();

            return results;
        }

    }   //  Program
}       //  ns
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this in SQL you could (untested and not optimized):

Use the code on [this blog entry](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/169/T-SQL-Converting-between-Decimal-Binary-and-Hexadecimal.aspx) to create a function to convert an int to a string representation of the binary representation of an int:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Int2Binary (@i INT) RETURNS NVARCHAR(16) AS BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i & 32768 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i & 16384 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  8192 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  4096 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  2048 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &  1024 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   512 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   256 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &   128 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    64 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    32 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &    16 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     8 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     4 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     2 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END +
        CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @i &     1 ) > 0 THEN '1' ELSE '0'   END
END;
GO
```

And follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906296/74015) to create a function to count the occurrences of a string in a substring.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CountOccurrencesOfString
(
    @searchString nvarchar(max),
    @searchTerm nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    return (LEN(@searchString)-LEN(REPLACE(@searchString,@searchTerm,'')))/LEN(@searchTerm)
END
```

And then mash them together like peanut butter and jelly:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Cheeses
ORDER BY CountOccurrencesOfString('1', Int2Binary(Characteristics))
```