# BigQuery: filter according to counts in nested field

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

I am trying to look up records that have 5 or more mentions of "BE" or "Belgium" in a nested field.
The below query does not yield any results:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT

GKGRECORDID

FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
where _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-10-09') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-10-09')

and (V2Themes LIKE "%WB_%GROWTH%")

group by GKGRECORDID

having count(V2Locations LIKE "%BE%" OR V2Locations LIKE "%Belgium%")>5
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your data correctly, you are trying to count the number of occurrences of “BE” or “Belgium” in each one of your V2Themes records. Therefore, in the following example the count should be 4?

> 1#Russia#RS#RS##60#100#RS#2475;1#Venezuela#VE#VE##8#-66#VE#471;1#Venezuela#VE#VE##8#-66#VE#1435;1#Venezuela#VE#VE##8#-66#VE#1521;1#Venezuela#VE#VE##8#-66#VE#2409;1#Russian#RS#RS##60#100#RS#2440;4#Brussels,
>   Bruxelles-Capitale,
>   Belgium#BE#BE11#5850#50.8333#4.33333#-1955538#673;4#Brussels,
>   Bruxelles-Capitale,
>   Belgium#BE#BE11#5850#50.8333#4.33333#-1955538#2342;4#Quito, Pichincha,

If that is correct, one possible workaround would be the one explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch). Translating this solution into your needs (counting words instead of characters), I suggest to use the SPLIT method to divide the string with a given separator and count its elements with and without the strings you are searching for.This would be one solution for your problem:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT

GKGRECORDID,

(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(V2Locations, '#')) - ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(REPLACE(V2Locations, '#BE', ''), "#"))) + (ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(V2Locations, '#')) - ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(REPLACE(V2Locations, '#Belgium', ''), "#"))) as bel_num,

V2Locations

FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
where _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2019-10-09') AND TIMESTAMP('2019-10-09')

and (V2Themes LIKE "%WB_%GROWTH%")

group by GKGRECORDID, V2Locations

having bel_num<5
```

Answer (score 1):

Few points here:

Instead of

```
 COUNT(V2Locations LIKE "%BE%" OR V2Locations LIKE "%Belgium%")>5
```

you should use

```
COUNTIF(V2Locations LIKE "%BE%" OR V2Locations LIKE "%Belgium%")>5
```

Even with above fix - you still will not get what you expect because you are targeting just one partition and in that partition max count of rows with the same `GKGRECORDID` is just `2`, so obviously there is no way to output `GKGRECORDID` which have more than `5` of anything