# SQL get numbers that contain certain digits

Tags: sql

How do I get number field that contain 878 as reflected in the result. It should contain two 8 and one 7.

Edit : using TSQL

| Number |
| --- |
| 878 |
| 780 |
| 788 |
| 700 |

| Result |
| --- |
| 878 |
| 788 |

Comment: What is your DBMS? What is the type of `Number` column

Comment: Youll need a custom function most likely...try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch

Comment: Are all numbers exactly 3 digits long? Could there be eg. 7888 and should this be excluded?

Comment: @KekuSemau yes all are 3 digits

Answer (score 2):

There are only 3 combinations so what about the crudest of them all?

```
Number = 788 OR Number = 878 OR Number = 887
```

Or even:

```
Number IN (788,878,887)
```

If numbers are not just 3 digits then cast the number as string and then:

```
NumberAsString LIKE '%887%' OR NumberAsString LIKE '%878%' OR NumberAsString LIKE '%788%'
```

Comment: `should contain two 8 and one 7` are even only 3 numbers

Answer (score 2):

A three digit number consisting of exactly one seven and two eights:

```
where number in (788, 878, 887)
```

Everything else would be overkill for this simple task.

If the task were different, say, the number can have more digits and must contain exactly one seven and two eights, then we could use an appropriate combination of `LIKE` and `NOT LIKE` to get what we are looking for. E.g:

```
where number like '%7%' -- contains a 7
  and number like '%8%8%' -- contains two 8s
  and number not like '%7%7%' -- doesn't contain more than one 7
  and number not like '%8%8%8%' -- doesn't contain more than two 8s
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
This is not a good solution, in stead I would go for the next solution suggested here.

If you are using MySQL REGEX is your friend:

```sql
SELECT * FROM _TABLE_ 
WHERE `Number` REGEXP "[7]{1}" AND `Number` REGEXP "[8]{2}";
```

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

I think in SQL Server should be something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM _TABLE_ 
WHERE `Number` LIKE '%[7]{1}%' AND `Number` LIKE '%[2]{1}%';
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @KhoaHoàng What DBMS are you using? Why you cannot use {} ?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18384.0 . not result if i run this query

Comment: `[8]{2}` will match `788`, `887` etc but not `878`

Comment: `[8]{2}` would be literally just `88`, and `[7]{1}` = `7` right? Looks like overcomplication to me.

Comment: I am agreed, sems this is not a good solution, in stead I would go with @tymtam suggestion

Comment: This way is much better, try to get it right @enriqueojedalara