# What is alternative function in sql REGEXP_COUNT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the variable in Oracle I need to convert in SQL Server please suggest.

```
V_BAD_EMAIL_CNT NUMBER :=  REGEXP_COUNT(pv_bad_emails,',') + 1;
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support regex, so we would need to see exactly what pattern you are trying to count here.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the number of comma's in the string + 1 in SQL

```
 declare @pv_bad_emails varchar(1000);
 set @pv_bad_emails = 'a,b,c,d';
 select len(@pv_bad_emails) - len(replace(@pv_bad_emails, ',', '')) + 1
```

For more reference

[How do you count the number of occurrences of a certain substring in a SQL varchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738282/how-do-you-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-certain-substring-in-a-sql-varch)